# Android simple WebView crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm creating a simple application right now and I add a webview on the bottom of screen.
The webview is on first page, so when I run the application the webview run.
But I got an error.

I just use a simple code, just for showing the content of web.

Here's my xml code

```
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

and here's my java code

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.loadUrl("http://www.tutorialspoint.com");
```

I already added internet permission on manifest.

Here's the logcat

```
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152): Process: com.indomultimedia.hellobali, PID: 25152
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.indomultimedia.hellobali/com.indomultimedia.hellobali.MainHelloballi}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at com.indomultimedia.hellobali.MainHelloballi.onCreate(MainHelloballi.java:58)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
06-26 10:09:18.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25152):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is line 58 of MainHelloballi ?

Comment: android:layout_height="0dip" ??

Comment: I already add the answer. Line 58 is the that i forgot to delete.

@Umitk 0dip because I use layout_weight. :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your Activity with setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); ?, this is on the onCreate method of the activity, or in a fragment like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, rootView, false);
```

This is on the `onCreateView(LayoutInflater,View,Bundle);`

Comment: Sorry @Kedarnath I was on my Cellphone when I wrote that Comment.

Comment: No problem, Here are other users who would like to make perfect editing :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I got the answer before anyone answer it.
There's an imageview that I delete it, but I forget remove the code on my MainHellobali java.

There's nothing wrong with the code.